# Ruby on Rails | AirBrake Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to run a project that was provided by a client.

I have the correct versions of Ruby, Gems, Rails, Bundler, Homebrew etc installed.

When I run `rails server` I get the following error in terminal.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/airbrake-ruby-1.0.4/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:288:in `call_notifier': the 'default' notifier isn't configured (Airbrake::Error)
```

After much time spent on Google I couldn't find a fix on this.

Here is a screenshot of the whole terminal error message which I get the feeling these other lines could be related.

[image]

Comment: I'd start by removing the `?` in the folder name and seeing if that rectifies the issue.

Comment: Haha I couldn't help but giggle when I saw this thinking how funny would that be if it was the fix. Removed it - re ran - still getting same issue. Good catch tho!

Comment: okay. what exactly is on line 5 on `config/environments/development.rb` ?

Comment: File.symlink("../../" + commit_hook_template, Rails.root + commit_hook)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a previous developer may have hardcoded a commit hook in the application, pointing to a file in their local `.git` folder (and which you don't have).

I'd recommend either asking the developer to provide the missing file, create a dummy file in the same place, or removing that line.

Comment: You sir are a legend

Comment: Ok I removed the line, ran "rails server" and got the following: 

bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/JordanVialoux/Development/Clients/Which/reviews-and-advice-develop/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here